# jQuery slider with buttons is buggy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, dom

This the html:

```
<div id = "slideshow">
  <div id="slideshowWindow">
    <div class="slide"><img src="slideshow.jpg" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="DSC_8185.jpg" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="DSC_8211.jpg" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="OrganicSoilad.jpg" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="DSC_8243.jpg" alt="" /></div>
  <input style = "display: none;"  value = "" id="hide"/>
</div>
```

Everything seems to work fine except for the prev() button. It just bugs out if you click it more than once. It gets all buggy. I'm relatively new to jquery and if anyone has any insight on how to stop the slider from sliding while on hover that would also be helpful.

the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".content").mouseenter(function(){
        $( ".arrows" ).fadeIn(100);
    });

    $('.content').mouseleave(function(){
        $( ".arrows" ).fadeOut(700);

    });

    var currentPosition = 0;
    var $hide = $('#hide');
    $hide.val(currentPosition);
    var slideWidth = 1140; 
    var slides = $('.slide'); var numberOfSlides = slides.length; var slideShowInterval; 
    var speed = 5000; slideShowInterval = setInterval(changePosition, speed); 
    slides.wrapAll('<div id="slidesHolder"></div>'); 
    slides.css({ 'float' : 'left' }); 

    $('#slidesHolder').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides); 

    function changePosition() { 
        currentPosition = $('#hide').val();

        if(currentPosition == numberOfSlides - 1)
        {
             currentPosition = 0; $hide.val(currentPosition); 
        } else { 
             currentPosition++; $hide.val(currentPosition); 
        } 
        moveSlide();
    } 

    function moveSlide() { 
         $current = $('#slidesHolder').css('padding-left');
         $current_num  = $current.replace('px' , '');
         $padding = $current_num;      
        $('#slidesHolder').animate({'paddingLeft': $padding});
       /* alert($padding);   */
        /*alert($('#slidesHolder').css('padding-left')); */
        $('#slidesHolder').animate({'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)}); 
        $('#media').html(currentPosition);

    }
});
function next()
{   
    currentPosition = $('#hide').val();
    slideWidth = 1140;
    ++currentPosition; if(currentPosition > 4){currentPosition =0;}
    $('#slidesHolder').animate({'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)});

    $('#hide').val(currentPosition) 
    $('#media').html(currentPosition); 
}

function prev()
{
    currentPosition = $('#hide').val();
    slideWidth = 1140;
     $left = 1140;
     if(currentPosition == 0)
     {

     currentPosition = 5;
     }
     else
     {
     if($('#slidesHolder').css('padding-left') == '1140px')
     {
         $left = $left + $left;
     }

    $('#hide').val(currentPosition); 

    $('#slidesHolder').animate({'paddingLeft' : $left});


    if(currentPosition == 0)
    {
        currentPosition = 4;
    }
    else{
        --currentPosition; 
    }

    $('#hide').val(currentPosition); 

    $('#media').html(currentPosition);
     }
}
```

Comment: A [Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) would be nice to help us help you

Comment: if u want help , please supply jsFiddle